# IText7 nested table on auto layout column

Tags: c#, itext7

I have to create a document with tables and nested tables. When the nested table is added to a column with a fixed width (in my example this is the first column with a width of 150pt) the nested table looks as expected (first column auto, second 70pt). But If I add the same nested table to a column where the width should automatically be adapted the columns of the nested table seems to be changed to auto as well. Is there something I have missed?

nested table example

[image: nested table example]

The code to generate this example looks as follow

```
public void Test(){
    //using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    var file = string.Format(@"c:\sample{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid());
    var rand = new Random();
    using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(file)))
    using (var doc = new Document(pdfDoc))
    {
    var table = new Table(new[] { UnitValue.CreatePointValue(150), UnitValue.CreatePointValue(0), UnitValue.CreatePointValue(0), UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(25)});
    //table.SetWidthPercent(100);
    for (var i = 0; i < table.GetNumberOfColumns(); i ++ )
    {
        var column = table.GetColumnWidth(i);
        table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().SetBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY).SetMargin(0).Add(column.ToString()));
    }

    const string sampledata = "01234567";
    for (var i = 0; i < table.GetNumberOfColumns() * 6; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 6:
                table.AddCell(new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(@"c:\demo.jpg")));
                break;
            case 4:
            {
                var subTable = CreateSubTable("subtable", rand);
                table.AddCell(new Cell().SetMargin(0).SetPadding(0).Add(subTable));
                break;
            }
            case 9:
            {
                var subTable = CreateSubTable("subtable", rand);
                table.AddCell(new Cell().SetMargin(0).SetPadding(0).Add(subTable));
                break;
            }
            default:
                table.AddCell(sampledata.Substring(0, rand.Next(1, sampledata.Length)));
                break;
        }
    }
    doc.Add(table);
}


private static Table CreateSubTable(string sampledata, Random rand){
    var subTable = new Table(new[] {UnitValue.CreatePointValue(0), UnitValue.CreatePointValue(70)});
    for (var h = 0; h < subTable.GetNumberOfColumns(); h++)
    {
        var column = subTable.GetColumnWidth(h);
        subTable.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().SetBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY).SetMargin(0).Add(column.ToString()));
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < subTable.GetNumberOfColumns() * 4; j++)
    {
        subTable.AddCell(sampledata.Substring(0, rand.Next(1, sampledata.Length)));
    }
    return subTable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you've missed something.

First of all, you can check the latest itext7 snapshot version and find your code working as you expect. [See the result pdf](http://docdro.id/fh4ayLI)

The difference is that in 7.0.2 auto layout itext do not consider column width in max width calculations. That has been changed and that's why now your code will work as you expect.

However, in certain conditions the same nested table will be processed differently. It depends on available width (in your case for second column - column with width to be calculated automatically). So generally speaking with certain cell content that will be impossible to place nested table as it should be (0 pt, 70 pt), and itext will squeeze the second column.

The good news is that we received too many questions about auto layout algorithm and decided to write some detailed documentation. I believe that will be finished in a week. And then everybody will be happy =)